# .hgignore website refresh files

Tags: asp.net, mercurial, hgignore

My ASP.NET website references refresh files that are being excluded because they reside in the `...\bin\` directory of projects.

What can I add to my .hgignore file to ensure just the `...\bin\*.refresh` files are NOT excluded?

Note: I understand I could use `hg add ...\bin\my.dll.refresh` for each of the references and continue with my `.hgignore`, but I'd like to avoid needing to manually add specific files types as this is error prone and easy to forget.

```
# use glob syntax
syntax: glob

# Ignore Visual Studio 2008 files
src/**.obj
src/**.exe
src/**.pdb
src/**.user
src/**.aps
src/**.pch
src/**.vspscc
src/**_i.c
src/**_p.c
src/**.ncb
src/**.suo
src/**.tlb
src/**.tlh
src/**.bak
src/**.cache
src/**.ilk
src/**.log
src/**.lib
src/**.sbr
src/**.scc
src/***/[Bb]in      <---- Problem child
src/***/[Dd]ebug*/
src/***/obj/*
src/***/[Rr]elease*/
src/*_ReSharper*/
src/*[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
src/*[Bb]uild[Ll]og.*
src/*.[Pp]ublish.xml
src/***/PrecompiledWeb/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "all except some names" you must use:

- regexp pattern
- add negative lookahead in regexp "all files"(get "all except in *this* subset" as result)

`syntax: regexp`

`bin/(?!.*\.refresh$).+`

in any case, check and debug this expression, using filenames with pattern `bin\*.*refresh*` and `hg status` command

Comment: Adding your code blocks and removing the `src/***/[Bb]in` from the `glob` section solved it perfectly.  This answer really could solve several of the similar questions posted on SO. Thank you.